# Unknown C++ exception while drawing matches using cv2.line_descriptor.drawLineMatches() in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I am trying to match line descriptors extracted from two images using the **binary descriptor module** of OpenCV in Python. But, when drawing the matches using `cv2.line_descriptor.drawLineMatches()` function, I am getting the below error

```
img3 = cv2.line_descriptor.drawLineMatches(img,keylines1,field,keylines2,matches[:10],None)
```

cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code

What's wrong I am doing? Any suggestion would help. Thanks.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

#Read gray image
img = cv2.imread("8.jpg",0)
field = cv2.imread('field1.png',0)

lsd = cv2.line_descriptor.LSDDetector.createLSDDetector()


#Detect lines in the image
keylines1 = lsd.detect(img, scale=2, numOctaves=2)
keylines2 = lsd.detect(field, scale=2, numOctaves=2)


# # # compute descriptors for lines
bd = cv2.line_descriptor.BinaryDescriptor.createBinaryDescriptor()
k1,descr1 = bd.compute(img, keylines1)
k2,descr2 = bd.compute(field, keylines2)

bdm =  cv2.line_descriptor.BinaryDescriptorMatcher()

matches = bdm.match(descr1, descr2)

matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
#img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img,k1,field,k2,matches[10],None,1)

img3 = cv2.line_descriptor.drawLineMatches(img,keylines1,field,keylines2,matches[:10],None)

#Show image
cv2.imshow("LSD",img3 )
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: please provide your input images to make your problem reproducible [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in the Python to C++ binding in [cv2.line_descriptor.drawLineMatches](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.16/dc/ddd/group__line__descriptor.html#ga01e43c974ddb735d39dd7124499f40ab) method.
When adding the `matchesMask` argument, the method seems to work.

Note that the code is working only with very specific versions of OpenCV.
The `LSDDetector` was removed in OpenCV version 4 (it may be part of the reason that the bug is not fixed).

The following example is working with `opencv-contrib-python` version `3.4.18.65`:

```
...

matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

good_matches = np.ones(10, np.uint8)

#Recommended to use colored images:
#img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
#field = cv2.cvtColor(field, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

img3 = cv2.line_descriptor.drawLineMatches(img, keylines1, field, keylines2, matches[:10], None, matchColor=-1, singleLineColor=-1, matchesMask=good_matches)
```

Comment: The above code is also valid for opencv-contrib-python version 4.6.0.66, and if the `matchesMask` parameter is not given, running the code with @Saikat does not report an error, but simply exits without any response.